# Android Studio da error al conectar con API en PHP usando Volley

Tags: php, api, http, android-volley

estoy usando volley para hacer una petición POST en HTTP a una API en PHP que he creado. Esta API insertará en una base de datos el valor que recibe. Su código es el siguiente:

```
//datos para la conexión
$usuario = "******";
$password = "******";
$servidor = "*******";
$basedatos = "*******";

//creacion de la conexion
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password) or die("Fallo en la conexión");

$db = mysqli_select_db($conn, $basedatos);

$name = $_POST["name"];

//sentencia sql y ejecución de esta
$sql = "INSERT INTO txumino VALUES($name)";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die("Error");

//cerrando la conexíon
mysqli_close($conn);
```

El código de Android con el que hago esta petición es el siguiente:

```
    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_POST, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),error+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("name",n);

            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(sr);
```

Este código está en dentro de una función a la que llamo al pulsar un botón. Esta mandaría a la API de PHP el valor de un editText.

Los errores que recibo en el Logcat al ejecutar el código son los siguientes:

> KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
>
> D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
>
> I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
>
> D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

Por otra parte en el mensaje TOAST que aparece por pantalla solo sale "Error" sin especificar porque ha sido este mismo y al mirar en la base de datos no se ha insertado nada nuevo.

Comment: Parece ser un problema de permisos,  ¿tienes todos los permisos requeridos en el `Manifest`? ¿La dirección contenida en `URL_POST` funciona si la ejecutas directamente en un navegador?

Comment: La URL si funciona, la he probado con webs que he hecho. En el manifest añadí el permiso de Internet, no sé si es necesario añadir algo más

Comment: Sólo por descartar lo de los permisos, agrega también estos para probar: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: Sigue dando los mismos errores

Comment: ¿Acaso estás probando la App en un dispositivo Samsung? Si es así, ¿tendrías posibilidad de probarla en otro dispositivo de otra marca o en el emulador? En una pregunta de SO en inglés decían que estos dispositivos daban el error `KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported`. ¿La URL es `https`? Podría ser un problema de certificados también...

Comment: Si lo estoy probando con un Samsung pero no tengo ningún móvil a mano. Y es http.

Comment: He probado con un dispositivo virtual que no era de Google y nada